# How to evenly space images to reduce white space?

Tags: graphics

I just started learning LaTeX yesterday and getting used to all of the syntax and jargon. I apologize if this question is asked profusely, but perhaps I don't know the keywords.

I am wondering how to evenly space images to reduce whitespace (see image below).

Many posts are referring to eliminating whitespace above and below images after insertion or talking about floating environments. Is it that I am not using the correct environment for inserting .png images?

Here is what I have written:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Classwork\Spring 2020\CHE304\Online Lab 3\Non-Inverting Input"} }
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.7cm, outer=2.7cm, top=2cm,  bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \title{\Large{\textbf{Module VI: Operational Amplifiers}}}
    \author{me}
    \date{April 28, 2020}
    \maketitle

\newpage

    \section{Non-Inverting Operational Amplifier}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{A non-inverting operational amplifier with a gain of 2}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{./Non-InvertingInput/non-inverting-input.png}
        \label{circuit}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{A non-inverting operational amplifier with a gain of 2}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm]{./Non-InvertingInput/gain2x.png}
        \label{chart1}
    \end{figure}

\newpage
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of code above]

Comment: This line will have given errors `\graphicspath{ {"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Classwork\Spring 2020\CHE304\Online Lab 3\Non-Inverting Input"} }` you need to use `/` not `\ ` even on windows, but better to simply delete it, it is not needed if the images are in the folder with the document.

Comment: Hahaha thank you! I suppose it didn't throw any errors because I have been manually designating the paths below.

Comment: There doesn't seem anything wrong with the figure spacing, you could reduce the lengths `\floatsep` and `\intextsep` but do you really want them closer together? best to ignore the spacing until you have written more text as it will adjust anyway depending on the text added. in a document with just two figures and no text latex does not have many options for positioning the figures well.

Comment: It is the space at the bottom that I am considering. Such that the blank space before the new page is not as prominent. The next page has a figure that will not accommodate all three appropriately.

Comment: sure but if your whole document just said `hello world` there would also be a space at the bottom. If you write  some words they will (or may) fill that space. With the document as posted what could latex fill the space with?

Comment: You are preventing the figures going to pages with just figures by using `[htb]` the main effect is to remove the option `p` of having a page of figures (this makes it _much_ more likely that the figures have no legal place and drift to the end of the document)

Comment: Here is what comes after the second image :[link](https://imgur.com/a/nVCbDd6)

Comment: your example as posted above really isn't an example  of the problem  that you are asking about then:-)  It is always best to post examples as complete documents that show the issue and allow answers to be tested (you can use `example-image` as the image) maybe you want `[!b]` on the second float to flush it to the bottom.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you!! I am sorry, you are right. I did not consider that I was not giving enough context. That solved my issue, thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can (most likely) force the second float to the bottom of the page by using `[!b]` but only do this after all editing done as float positioning depends on the surrounding text not just the figures themselves.